# A better tool than Fixtures to populate a Django Database?

Tags: python, django

I set fixtures in my Django project to populate my database. This works well but has a serious limit: you can't create lots of stuff.

In theory, you can put as much elements as you want, but since you need to write them one by one, it's impossible to have 20 000 items in your db.

I need a tool that would fill the primary keys itself, and would be able to generate random typed data to fill the fixtures (e.g: emails, integers in a range, dates in a range, phones). Another nice functionally would be to set functional rules in data generation.

Does someone knows a way (library, ...) to do this in a Django project?
I took a look at https://github.com/joke2k/faker - the tool itself seems good, but no integration with Django.

Otherwise, I guess I could write it myself using Faker (since writing a fixture file just consists on json generation), but I don't like to reinvent the wheel :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factory Boy: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org

It's a fixtures replacement that works really well for unit testing or otherwise making fixture data. You can write classes that hook into your models and generate populated model instances and you can construct them to save to the database, or not.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm gonna watch it. I found https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-faker/0.2 too. Do you know this one?

Comment: @DavidW.: I haven't used that one, no. And I'm not sure whether it's appealing to you or not, but Factory Boy is framework-agnostic, it just has Django integration included with it, along with SQLAlchemy, Mongoengine, and Mogo ORM integration.